# Is sets being zero distance apart a topological property?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$, then $d(A,B) = inf_{a\in A,b\in B} d(a,b)$.  Now it is possible for $d(A,B)$ to be zero even if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, or even if their closures are disjoint.

My question is, is the concept of two sets being zero distance apart a topological property?  That is to say, if $d_1$ and $d_2$ induce the same topology on $X$, then is it necessarily true that $d_1(A,B)=0$ if and only if $d_2(A,B)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\Bbb R^2$ be the Euclidean plane. Let $A$ be the $x$-axis, and $B$
the graph of $y=e^x$. Then in the usual distance, $d(A,B)=0$.

Define a homeomorphism $X\to X$ by $F(x,y)=(x,e^{-x}y)$. Then $F(A)=A$
and $F(B)$ is the line $y=1$, so $d(F(A),F(B))=1$.

So we can take $d_1$ to be the Euclidean metric, and $d_2(a,b)
=d_1(F(a),F(b))$. These both give the standard topology, but $d_1(A,B)=0<d_2(A,B)$.